# Facebook Graph API always returns 0 as count for CARE reaction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am collecting reactions for Facebook posts on public pages. This works for the classic reactions (like, haha, angry, ...). However, Facebook at times also offered reactions such as thankful, pride, or currently care.

According to the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/reactions) something like this should work (also in older versions of the API such as 3.2 which I am using):

```
16673188972_10160314322883973?fields=
reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(true).as(like),
reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(true).as(love),
reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(true).as(haha),
reactions.type(CARE).limit(0).summary(true).as(care),
reactions.type(THANKFUL).limit(0).summary(true).as(thankful)
```

For a (random) post with ID 16673188972_10160314322883973 found here https://www.facebook.com/JennyLewis/posts/10160314322883973 it returns the correct number for likes (812), for love (346), for haha (1), but not for care. I get 0 for care reactions, although there are at this point 15 care reactions for this post. I have tested this with a few posts that have care reactions and care reactions are always 0 (as are thankful and pride reactions which are not available at the time—however, I did not look up posts with these reactions to them). Has anyone experienced the same thing (or managed to get correct CARE reactions through the Facebook API)?

Here the post:
[FB post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUwTW.png)

Here my API testing call:
[Graph API test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSx4f.png)

EDIT: Added "limit(0)" to reflect my real API call. This did not change anything. I also ran the same thing now on one of my own posts with API version 7.0. Same result. However, I recognized that the "special" reaction CARE was counted as a regular like. So maybe there is no possibility to capture the number of CARE reactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently two bug reports pending:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/236778101089217/
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/686426458757119/?locale=en_US

It exactly matched my description and was reproduced and assigned to developers by Facebook. So maybe, this will be fixed soon.

Sorry for not checking Facebook bug reports earlier. I will update this answer if the problem gets fixed.

UPDATE [2020-07-03]: Apparently, this behavior is by design (see links to the bug reports above). Facebook won't change it. Temporary reactions will be subsumed under "likes". So there will be no "fix". Temporary reactions such as "care" are counted as likes.